NAV2 Custom Robot is not following path while moving
I prepared a custom robot and whenever I publish velocity from the teleop, it moves well. My robot hasn't got IMU but it is localizing and mapping via LIDAR. It generates a map successfully with ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py.
Whenever I publish 2D Goal Pose it starts move but it was not moving to the target point correctly. After a while it gives the following errors:
[controller_server]: Failed to make progress
planner loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000 hz nav2. Current Hz is between 1 and 1.4
My .yaml file is the same given in the nav2 documents website: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2_tutorials/blob/master/sam_bot_description/config/nav2_params.yaml
I only changed the robot size.

There are way too many variables in this question to answer is. Please provide a lot more details!
Regarding the error: the control-loop of the controller is not executing fast enough to satisfy the rate of 20Hz, which can have multiple reasons. Most likely the (default) controller you used does not work with the given kinematics of your "custom robot" and needs parameter-tuning.
